# PHP Imagemagick script for processing Wordpress images

Tags: php, wordpress, imagemagick, timthumb

I would like to replace the Timthumb script in my Wordpress template with PHP Imagick. Does anyone has a script I can use? I also would like to use a cache directory for better performance.

I'm now using `timthumb.php?src=/<?php echo $imgurl; ?>&w=215&h=150&zc=1&q=100"`